# Event onClick ImageView calling when i click everywhere on item

Tags: android, image, onclick, listener, android-arrayadapter

I have got a problem with my Listener, i create a list with an ArrayAdapter and i set a text and an image for every item with WML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_macro"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_delete"
        android:src="@drawable/button_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And a listener for the images.
But the event is calling when i click on the item, same when i click not on the image..

My adapter class:

```
public class ListEditable extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {


private final int rowResourceId;

public ListEditable(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Integer> macros) {
    super(context, resource, macros);
    this.rowResourceId = resource;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = (View) inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_macro);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("toast");

            }
        });
    textView.setText(this.getItem(position));
    return rowView;

}
```

And i have an other problem, maybe it came for the same reason,
i haven't the image focus when i click on my image, however i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_delete_focus" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_delete_focus" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_delete"/>

</selector>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Maybe because of the android:layout_width="fill_parent" try changing it to wrap_content

Comment: Why not use the listview's click listener instead of setting the listener on individual view components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly. The solution is:

Change your `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` of ImageView to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

As you are taking `RelativeLayout` and you have specified the value of width of `imageView` as `fill_parent` thats why it takes the whole width of an item in list.

Change your `ImageView` with the following

```
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_delete"
        android:src="@drawable/button_delete" />
```

This worked for me.Hope it works for you too
If you want more help then also let me know